# Confusion with keyof

Tags: typescript

Why does this code not throw any errors:

```
interface X {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

type Y<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: boolean;
}

class A<Definition> {
    constructor(public readonly definition: Definition, public readonly fields: Y<Definition>) {

    }
}

const y = {
    a: true,
    c: false
}


const a = new A<X>({a: 'first', b: 'second'}, y)
```

But this throws an error?

```
interface X {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

type Y<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: boolean;
}

const y: Y<X> = {
  a: true,
  c: false,
}
```

I'm looking to have something similar to the first example throw an error because `c` is not a key of `X`.

If I add the type `Y<X>` to `y` in the first example, I get a compiler error.

Comment: Do you know about [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) in fresh object literals?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use union types to make your 2nd example code work:

```
interface X {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

type Y<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: boolean;
}

type Z = {
    c: boolean;
}

const y: Y<X> | Z = {
    a: true,
    c: false
}
```